# Angular Js Simulating Enter on Tab Key press

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to simulate Enter on Tab key press in angular js.I wanted to implement it in angular's chips.I have done some research and couldn't find any appropriate answers for it. Below is the sample code.

**HTML**

```
<chips defer ng-model="item_titles_order.item_titles_orders.$selected_imei[$index]" render="batchesView.imeiValidation(data)"  ng-keydown="batchesView.triggerEnter($event)" id = 'yourInput'>
    <chip-tmpl>
        <div class="default-chip ">
            <span>{{chip.defer}}</span>
            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" remove-chip style="margin: 0px;">
            </i>
        </div>
    </chip-tmpl>
    <input  placeholder="Type/Scan IMEI" chip-control></input>
</chips>
```

**Controller function**

```
vm.triggerEnter = function(keyEvent) {
    if(keyEvent.keyCode==9){
        var e = $.Event("keydown");
        e.which = 13;
        e.keyCode = 13;
        $("#triggerEnter").trigger(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: what you are trying to achieve by simulating enter ? what happens on enter event ?

Comment: why   would you want to simulate enter key ?

Comment: client is making mistake while submitting the data. So I want to provide them one more option where they can submit data using tab key too. I have no Idea how to tell them that this angular chips functionality doesn't work that way.

Comment: http://formvalidation.io/examples/selectize/ this solved my problem